# What is a beggar's bench?

Tags: meaning

> The monk seated himself on **the beggars’ bench** by the door, and
> would have naught but cold porridge and water for his supper.
>
> ---
>
> *From "Kristin Lavransdatter" by Sigrid Undset.*

Does this insinuate some part of end seats of a long bench placed at the entrance of  a house in medieval age?

Comment: Obviously this was originally in Swedish. I read it in translation years ago. Presumably the expression refers to a seat where poor people could wait for charitable donations of food, but this isn't really an English language question.

Comment: This is actually an excellent question. A beggar's bench [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGWxz.jpg) a regular bench, but its seat is hinged, so it can be lifted up. Underneath the seat is storage. I would have posted this as an answer, but I can't find any sources that provide such a definition, so it would have been an unsubstantiated claim on my part. I'm guessing the name comes from the fact that beggars can both sit on it and keep anything they've been given inside. (But that's just a guess, and it doesn't seem likely to be a literal interpretation.)

Comment: @JasonBassford interesting - to the best of my knowledge it seems to be a calque of French 'banc de quêteux', as per eg. https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-1995-05-21-9505210607-story.html ("(...) as he sat on a banc de queteux, or beggars' bench, a rustic 19th Century sofa bed used by farm families to welcome itinerant strangers.")

Comment: @JasonBassford Interesting indeed. I had never heard the expression here in the UK and can't find much online except for (mainly Canadian) antique shops. I wonder what it was in the original Swedish.

Comment: My parents (in the UK) had something similar to the image @JasonBassford linked to which was referred to as a monk's seat. I have no idea why.

Comment: *On a recent tour of her house, Mrs. Linz pointed out a number of unique features that also survived, including a beggars' bench positioned near a side entrance.

"Beggars who came to the door were offered a meal and could sit in the hall and eat it, but never with the family in the dining room," she said.*  (about a house built in 1893) http://members.tripod.com/non_essential/WellsHomePlacePlanoTx.htm

Comment: @JasonBassford A [search of stock photography](https://www.alamy.com/search.html?pn=1&ps=100&qt=beggars%20bench%201800s&qt_raw=beggars%20bench%201800s) has similar looking benches, although they seem to pull out into a bed, not have storage: https://c8.alamy.com/comp/RXAFH8/pinewood-1830s-beggars-bench-and-green-wooden-boston-rocking-chair-from-1880s-in-living-room-inside-an-old-circa-1750-canadiana-style-fieldstone-hous-RXAFH8.jpg

Answer (score 2):

A beggar’s bench here in Quebec (banc de quêteux) is a long bench equipped with hinges so that the seat could be open to form a bed. That bed was used to host a beggar for a night. Sort of a hide-a-bed of old times. The homeowners would put hay in it as a mattress for the night which ensured that it would make noise if the beggar stood up during the night, which would alert the homeowners of the movement of their guest. Back in the day, beggars would go from town to town, begging and seeking shelter in houses along their way. People had a social and religious duty to help support the beggars and offer them a place to sleep especially during winter. I own such a bench made circa 1840.